# Hide every menu opened just after click a link from it

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I am making an Off Canvas sidebar dropdown menu in vanilla JS.
Almost at the bottom of my JS code I have made a function to hide the sidebar off canvas just after someone clicks an href link.
Also I have made a function to hide and show the hidden submenu level of the dropdown menu in order to click them.
But now I need a function to close every opened dropdown menu from the sidebar when a user clicks an href link, just before getting the user to anoher site page. Then, when the user opens again the menu all dropdowns will be closed.
NOTE: 'aTags' is the name of the variable that points to every clickeable href element
Any advice will be very helpfull!

```js
const open = document.querySelector('.open');
let list_items = document.querySelectorAll('#subb');
let overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
let aTags = open.getElementsByClassName('ilink');



// Show and Hide sidebar when click icon
let toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");

for (let i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  let toggle = toggles[i];
  toggleHandler(toggle);
};

function toggleHandler(toggle) {

  toggle.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) {
      this.classList.remove("is-active");
      open.classList.remove('oppenned');
      overlay.className = 'overlay';


    } else {
      this.classList.add("is-active");
      open.classList.add('oppenned');
      overlay.className += ' open';
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target === overlay) {
      toggle.classList.remove("is-active");
      open.classList.remove('oppenned');
      overlay.className = 'overlay';
    }
  });



  // hide sidebar off canvas when click a menu link
  for (let i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
    aTags[i].addEventListener("click", close);
  }

  function close(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    open.classList.remove('oppenned');
    toggle.classList.remove("is-active");
    overlay.className = 'overlay';


  }


  // Show and Hide the hidden Submenu ul
  for (let i = 0; i < list_items.length; i++) {
    list_items[i].addEventListener("click", show);
  }

  function show(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    this.classList.toggle("myClass");
  }


}
```

```css
.sub-menu ul ul {
  max-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
  background: white;
}

#subb.myClass>ul {
  max-height: 32em;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav" class="sub-menu open">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li id="subb">
      <a class="link">Soluciones</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="subb">
          <a class="link">Correo y herramientas colaborativas</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="link ilink" href="https://www.google.com/">Google Workspace</a></li>
            <li><a class="link ilink href=" https://www.google.com/ "">Google for Education</a></li>
            <li><a class="link ilink" href="https://www.google.com/">Microsoft 365</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


      </ul>
```